# Randomise an array from actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, random

```
public class Hangman extends Sprite {
    private var textDisplay:TextField;

    private var phrase:String = "Recycled" 
    private var phrase:String = "Stamped"
    private var phrase:String = "grandpa"
```

"What I want to do here is to randomise the "phrase:String", so that the phrase outcome will be either recycled, stamped or grandpa.

```
    private var shown:String;
    private var numWrong:int;

    public function Hangman() {
        // create a copy of text with _ for each letter
        shown = phrase.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g,"_");
        numWrong = 0;

        ...codes*
    }

    public function pressKey(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        // get letter pressed
        var charPressed:String = (String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));

        // loop through nd find matching letters
        var foundLetter:Boolean = false;
        for(var i:int=0;i<phrase.length;i++) {
            if (phrase.charAt(i).toLowerCase() == charPressed) {
                // match found, change shown phrase
                shown = shown.substr(0,i)+phrase.substr(i,1)+shown.substr(i+1);
                foundLetter = true;
            }
        }

        // update on-screen text
        textDisplay.text = shown;

        // update hangman
        if (!foundLetter) {
            numWrong++;
            character.gotoAndStop(numWrong+1);
        }
    }
}

 }
```

I hope someone can help me on this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same variable being instantiated with the same name... if you want, use an array to keep the possible words...

```
var phrase:Array = [ "Recycled", "Stamped", "grandpa", ...];
```

Then, use a Random function to select a number from 0, up to array size, then use that word...

```
var word = phrase[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrase.length)];
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I did it, and the bracket should be squared bracket instead of curly bracket. :)